# i'm having problems with URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I am using this code

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"c:\myvideo.avi";
```

but when the video file containing folder changed this code is not working.i need to set an permanent URL even though the file containing folder is changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t find the file if it’s location was changed. Imagine if the user moved it to another drive or permanently deleted it - what would you do then?

If you’re changing folder within your application then of course you can track where the file was placed and correspondingly change the path. But if the path was changed outside of your app you can’t do anything with it.